# False "missing route" inspection in PhpStorm w/ Symfony2 plugin

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

**Background**

One of the features of the Symfony2 plugin in PhpStorm is that it becomes aware of your routes, allowing for auto-completion and things like that.

However, right now, my plugin seems to believe that the route does NOT exist, when it does. See attached images:

[image]

For reference, here is the route debugger at work.

[image]

**Question**

Can this inspection be made aware of the routes?

**Extra notes**

This problem has existed for a while, both with and without a fresh cache.

Comment: How the route is defined. It's Symfony2 plugin that does such resolution/support and not PhpStorm (that is unaware of any special syntaxes/framework-specific functionality). It could be https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/828 / http://stackoverflow.com/q/40917416/783119 for example.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Go to `[File] --> [Invalidate Caches / Restart...]` . This solved my problem. However the project will be reindexed on the next start, which can take some time.

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm reads configured routes, services, etc. from the cache directory/files. Does your cache exist? If it does and you just added a new route, maybe you need to regenerate the cache.

- `app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php`

Comment: This problem has existed for a while, both with and without a fresh cache. Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: When you do a global find, does it find the cached instance of your route?

Answer (score 0):

Put double quote instead of single quote on the line with the route name. The inspector will be aware of the requested route.